# AJAX не передает атрибуты тегов

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Есть страничка на HTML

```
<tr id="call-Id" class="call-u">
        <td >Id</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Contact</td>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>Information</td>

</tr>
```

я ее получаю AJAX запросом, однако на странице на который я ее получаю не сохраняются атрибуты `id="call-Id" class="call-u"`, то есть на выходе мы получаем

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Contact</td>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>Info</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

как можно видеть, атрибуты у тэга `<tr>` не сохраняются.

такой вот скрипт:

```
function getdata() {
        var post = $.post("/Admin/getCalls")
        .success(processdata);

    }
    }
    function processdata(data) {
        var b = document.getElementById("calls-container");
        var c = document.getElementById("xml-container");
        al
        c.innerHTML = data;
        if (b.innerHTML != c.innerHTML) {
            b.innerHTML = data;
            var audio = new Audio('/Content/Sounds/ding.mp3');
            audio.play();

        }
    }
```

Comment: вы получаете какую-то другую таблицу...в последнем td info в одном варианте а в другом information...

Comment: это я что-то не то вставил, кстати говоря, само каким-то образом заработало

Comment: бывает) хорошо что все встало на свои места)

Comment: извините, хотел помоч, но так как нехватает репутации не смог прокоментировать...

Comment: @Борис ничего страшного, преобразовал ответ в комментарий. Зарабатывайте репутацию, всего-то на 50 можно будет комментировать )